# Keeping both uuid_ossp and pgcrypto in a rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm developing an old Rails project (rails 5) and in the old migrations they use `uuid_ossp` as the default primary key.

Since Gemfile doesn't specify `postgresql` version, I'm now using the newer version (`9.4`) to the one they used to create the project. In postgresql 9.4 `uuid_ossp` is replaced with `pgcrypto`. Hence when you create a new model, Rails will raise error `no function gen_random_uuid()`.

What I'm asking is that:

- should I keep my project enabling both `uuid_ossp` for older migrations and `pgcrypto` for newer ones,
- or should I migrate everything to `pgcrypto` and also lock `postgresql` to the current version?

Because at this moment all I have to do is enable `pgcrypto` in `config/application.rb` and everything just works without touching or modifying or locking anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it would be best to keep things as it is. I didn't try migrating from `uuid_ossp` to `pgcrypto` so I'm not sure if it's possible to do so, but sometimes the best solution is not doing anything at all.